# Implementing Custom/User control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, custom-controls

[image]

**Requirement:**

1. As shown in image a rectangular control needs to be divided into
   five regions.
2. It should be able to set a background color for each
   region.(BackgroundBrushProperty)
3. A mouse click event needs to be implemented for each region.(MouseDown Event)

**Question**

1. How can I create such control  in WPF?
2. Can I extent existing controls for this purpose?
3. What is the trick behind creating such shapes in WPF?

I guess creating a shape with multiple region is a big challenge in this requirement.

Can any one help me to implement this? Are there any online tutorials or articles available?
Providing an example will be highly appreciated!!

.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend a UserControl like below.

**.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.TileBlock"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="200"
    x:Name="self" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
  <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <Grid Width="40" Height="50">
      <Polygon Points="0,0 10,10 10,40 0,50" Fill="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=LeftBlockBackground}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" MouseDown="LeftBlock_MouseDown" />
      <Polygon Points="0,0 10,10 30,10 40,0" Fill="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=TopBlockBackground}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" MouseDown="TopBlock_MouseDown" />
      <Polygon Points="40,0 30,10 30,40 40,50" Fill="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=RightBlockBackground}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" MouseDown="RightBlock_MouseDown" />
      <Polygon Points="0,50 10,40 30,40 40,50" Fill="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=BottomBlockBackground}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" MouseDown="BottomBlock_MouseDown" />
      <Rectangle Width="20" Height="30" Fill="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=CentralBlockBackground}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" MouseDown="CentralBlock_MouseDown" />
    </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind **.cs**:

```
public partial class TileBlock : UserControl {
  public TileBlock() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  //Dependency properties for backgrounds
  public Brush LeftBlockBackground {
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(LeftBlockBackgroundProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LeftBlockBackgroundProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftBlockBackgroundProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("LeftBlockBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(TileBlock), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent));
  //... repeat for Top, Right, Bottom and Central

  public event MouseButtonEventHandler LeftBlockMouseDown;
  private void LeftBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    if (LeftBlockMouseDown != null) LeftBlockMouseDown(this, e);
    e.Handled = true;
  }
  //... repeat for Top, Right, Bottom and Central

  //... repeat for MouseEnter, MouseLeave, MouseMove etc. if necessary
}
```

Now you can put this UserControl to yours app:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <local:TileBlock LeftBlockBackground="Yellow" Width="80" Height="100" LeftBlockMouseDown="TileBlock_LeftBlockMouseDown" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Good luck!